# Added html, js, and css and now Ruby on Rails app won't compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added the necessary files under /app/assets/javascripts and /app/assets/stylesheets and changed my working index.html.erb file to this:

**index.html.erb**

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/assets/stylesheets/colorbox.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/assets/stylesheets/style.css">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Customer Analysis | Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>



    <div id="main-container">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="http://customers.priceanalytics.net/">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Customer Analysis</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab">
                        <li class="active" role="presentation">
                            <a href="#dashboard">Retention</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="" role="presentation">
                            <a href="#experiments">Cohort</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="" role="presentation">
                            <a href="#clv">Customer Lifetime Value</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="" role="presentation">
                            <a href="#mapped">Map</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="" role="filter">
                          <a href="#filter">Customer Audiences</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="dashboard">
                            <div class="row" id="retention"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="experiments">
                            <center>
                                <h2>Sales</h2>
                            </center>
                            <div class="row" id="cohorttable"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="filter" class="tab-pane fade">
                          <center><h2>Customer Audiences</h2></center>
                          <div id="crossfilter" class="row">
                            <div id="leftpane">
                              <div id="propertylist"></div>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary">Save data</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="rightpane">
                              <div id="charts"></div>
                              <aside id="totals"><span id="active">-</span> of <span id="total">-</span> customers fit the above criteria.</aside>
                              <div id="lists">
                                <table class="customer-list">
                                  <tr class="customer">
                                    <td class="shippingname">Shipping name</td>
                                    <td class="e-mail">e-mail</td>
                                    <td class="time">First date</td>
                                    <td class="time">Last date</td>
                                    <td class="currency">Total sales</td>
                                    <td class="currency">NPV</td>
                                    <td class="currency">AOV</td>
                                    <td class="smallnumber">Orders</td>
                                    <td class="smallnumber">Items</td>
                                    <td class="time">Time btw</td>
                                    <td class="zipcode">ZIP</td>
                                    <td class="gender">Gender</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                                <table id="customer-list" class="customer-list list"></table>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="clv">
                            <center>
                                <h2>Customer Lifetime Value</h2>
                            </center>
                            <div class="row" id="clv">
                                           <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><p>Repeat Customer Rate:</p><p><span cmd="repeat_cust_rate"></span>%</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><p>Average Order Value:</p><p>$<span cmd="avg_order_val"></span></p></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><p>Time Between Purchases:</p><p><span cmd="time_btw_purchase"></span></p></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><p>Purchase Frequency:</p><p><span cmd="purchase_frequency"></span></p></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><p>Customer Value:</p><p>$<span cmd="cust_value"></span></p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>

                            <script>
                var lifetimeValues = $('#clv').find('.col-md-2 span');

                lifetimeValues.each( function(){ 
                  $(this).html( clv_data[0][ $(this).attr('cmd') ].toFixed(2) );
                });

                            </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="mapped">
                            <div class="row" id="map"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="popup">
                <table></table>
            </div>
            <div id="selectioninfo">
                <table></table><button id="savedata" class="btn btn-primary">Save data</button>
            </div>           


                <script src=
                "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src=
                "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('#tab a').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).tab('show');
                    });
                });

            </script>
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script>
            <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js">
            </script>
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/sorttable.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/FileSaver.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script> 
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/crossfilter.v1.min.js">
            </script>
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/retention.js">
            </script> 
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/cohort.js">
            </script> 
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/map.js">
            </script> 
            <script src="/app/assets/javascripts/filter.js">
            </script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
                        $('#tab a').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $(this).tab('show');
                        });
                    });

            </script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('#tab a').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).tab('show');
                    });
                });

            </script>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When pushing to heroku I get the error:

```
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I still need to add some variables from Ruby in, but I thought this should work. I'm pretty new to Rails, is there a better way for me to setup the html pages? I've had this code working before on a Python version of this app.

**Heroku Log**

```
2016-10-10T20:12:20.148407+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-10T20:12:20.148413+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-10T20:12:20.278402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-10-10T20:12:20.278949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-10-10T20:12:22.031227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428123+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:12:22] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428134+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428135+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in
 start'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428136+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428136+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428137+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.r
b:34:in `run'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428138+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in
`start'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428138+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/s
erver.rb:80:in `start'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428142+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428144+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428145+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428146+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428146+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.r
b:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428147+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428148+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428306+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:12:22] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-10-10T20:12:22.428392+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:12:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-10-10T20:12:22.466742+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-10-10T20:12:22.466746+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:24845

2016-10-10T20:12:22.466747+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-10-10T20:12:22.466748+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-10-10T20:12:22.466749+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-10-10T20:12:22.573198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-10-10T20:12:23.456119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 38099 -e production`
2016-10-10T20:12:27.186333+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:12:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-10-10T20:12:27.186387+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:12:27] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-10-10T20:12:27.186771+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:12:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=38099
2016-10-10T20:12:27.581049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-10-10T20:13:15.340999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?hmac=b0022c2db596e836cdda8c136ee40b9f30f1333
b30f9bd86c06ee6e344096f0f&protocol=https%3A%2F%2F&shop=test-cust.myshopify.com&timestamp=1476130393" host=shop-test-2.he
rokuapp.com request_id=442d86b3-025d-46f9-9687-a6ee20384685 fwd="71.239.189.250" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=669ms st
atus=200 bytes=5014
2016-10-10T20:13:15.322516+00:00 app[web.1]: unknown OID 2278: failed to recognize type of 'retention_data'. It will be
treated as String.
2016-10-10T20:45:47.821178+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-10T20:46:03.679549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?hmac=a311893f64b3cb8689c24c1bdd962bcc1bede1e
258b538982bdf883595ca76e3&protocol=https%3A%2F%2F&shop=test-cust.myshopify.com&timestamp=1476132362" host=shop-test-2.he
rokuapp.com request_id=40dc5c2f-21ba-4ae7-9051-be7ff9d05eac fwd="71.239.189.250" dyno=web.1 connect=11ms service=413ms s
tatus=200 bytes=5014
2016-10-10T20:46:48.233219+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-10T20:47:29.144311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-10-10T20:47:29.145034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-10-10T20:47:31.536543+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209321+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:47:32] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209331+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209334+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in
 start'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209335+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209335+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209336+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.r
b:34:in `run'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209336+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in
`start'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209337+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/s
erver.rb:80:in `start'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209338+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209339+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209339+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209340+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209340+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.r
b:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209341+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209342+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209424+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:47:32] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-10-10T20:47:32.209467+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-10-10 20:47:32] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-10-10T20:47:32.243638+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-10-10T20:47:32.243644+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-10-10T20:47:32.243643+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:38099

2016-10-10T20:47:32.243644+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-10-10T20:47:32.243645+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-10-10T20:47:32.356245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-10-10T20:51:09.010661+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
```

Comment: Aren't you interested in why precompiling assets failed? Hint: look at the Heroku log.

Comment: I added the error log to the op, I'm still not clear on what the issue is tbh

Comment: You can precompile the assets on your development machine with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. Maybe that will show a better error message.

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: rake aborted!
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xA3" on UTF-8

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

Comment: I can see you solved your problem. What probably happened was that your sorttable.js was not UTF-8. Should you need it in the future, converting the file to UTF-8 should fix the problem also.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to drag out a cliche, but I think that it's applicable:

"Correlation does not imply causation."

You may have added assets to your Rails project prior to encountering this exception, but that doesn't mean those assets are the cause of the exception. [`SIGTERM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGTERM) is a UNIX signal originating from outside your project that more or less boils down to "please shut down." Your app is graciously accommodating this request by doing just that.

It's likely that the Heroku [dyno manager](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm) is the source of this signal. If you're using Heroku's free tier, you're going to run into this issue from time to time due to mandatory sleep time for dynos on that tier.

Try restarting your worker dyno by running:

```
heroku restart worker.1
```

On the off chance this problem isn't coming from the dyno manager, try changing your web server to a production grade offering. Heroku specifically [cautions against using WEBrick](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server), which is OK for development, but not so good for production. Although you may currently be in development, you might want to bite the bullet and work with the same setup that you're eventually going to be running in production.

I don't think WEBrick is the problem here, but you might as well get your ducks in a row now rather than later.

Comment: heroku restart worker.1 and heroku restart didn't seem to fix it. Looking into 'puma' now

Comment: @Adam12344 Check your gem file and make sure `rake` is included. The next step is to try to precompile your assets as Nils suggested in his comment. I still don't think adding assets necessarily caused the SIGTERM, but it's looking increasingly possible.

Comment: I removed all of the assets and it worked again. I added them back in one-by-one and found out it was sorttable.js that is the only file that is keeping it from compiling. Luckily, I no longer need this file